# Changing Stored Procedure Structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that currently gets information from multiple tables and displays the data. I now need it to no longer look at the `Order_Detail_Serials` table and look only at the `order_serial` table. I am not sure how to change the structure to do so. Any assistance in the matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Status]
(
  @begin_date as smalldatetime,
  @end_date as smalldatetime
)
AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Gather Orders with date range with product codes 
select distinct orders.ordernumber as Internal_id, 
        orders.ponumber as client_id, 
        orders.altordernumber as altonumber,
        orders.shipid as Shipping_method, 
        orders.shipdate as Ship_Date,
        order_details.productid as productid, 
        products.productcode as Parent_Item_Code, 
        orders.orderstatus as Order_Status
    into #Orders_Header_Info
    from orders
    inner join order_details
        on orders.ordernumber = order_details.ordernumber
    inner join products
        on order_details.productid = products.productid
    where orders.shipdate between @begin_date and @end_date
    order by internal_id 

-- Attach serial numbers to orders
select o.Internal_id,
        o.client_id,
        o.altonumber,
        o.shipping_method,
        o.ship_date,
        o.parent_item_code,
        os.status as Item_Status, 
        isnull(s.serial,'') as sn,
        o.order_status
    into #Orders_Detail_Serials         
    from #Orders_Header_Info o
    join order_detail_serials s
        on o.Internal_id = s.ordernumber
            and o.productid = s.productid
    join order_serial os
        on s.productid = os.productid
            and s.serial like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(os.sn)) + '%'


-- Concatenate tracking numbers
select ordernumber, [1] as tracknum1, 
        [2] as tracknum2, 
        [3] as tracknum3, 
        [4] as tracknum4, 
        [5] as tracknum5, 
        [6] as tracknum6, 
        [7] as tracknum7,
        [8] as tracknum8,
        [9] as tracknum9,
        [10] as tracknum10
    into #tracking
    from
        (
            select ordernumber, trackingnumber,
                    row_number() over (partition by ordernumber order by ordernumber)
                    as rownum
                from order_tracking
                where ordernumber in
                        (
                            select distinct internal_id
                                from #Orders_Detail_Serials
                        )
                    and isnull(publishedrate,0) <> 0

        ) tracknumbers
    pivot (max(trackingnumber) for rownum in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) as pvt


    -- Retrieve return tracking numbers
    -- dl 6-15-2015 commented, changed to concatenating return tracking number
    --select ordernumber, 
    --      trackingnumber as return_trackingnumber
    --  into #return_tracking
    --  from order_tracking
    --  where ordernumber in 
    --          (
    --              select distinct internal_id
    --                  from #Orders_Detail_Serials
    --          )
    --      and isnull(publishedrate,0) = 0


-- dl 6-12-2015 
-- Concatenate return tracking numbers
select ordernumber, [1] as tracknum1, 
        [2] as tracknum2, 
        [3] as tracknum3, 
        [4] as tracknum4, 
        [5] as tracknum5, 
        [6] as tracknum6, 
        [7] as tracknum7,
        [8] as tracknum8,
        [9] as tracknum9,
        [10] as tracknum10
    into #return_tracking
    from
        (
            select ordernumber, trackingnumber,
                    row_number() over (partition by ordernumber order by ordernumber)
                    as rownum
                from order_tracking
                where ordernumber in
                        (
                            select distinct internal_id
                                from #Orders_Detail_Serials
                        )
                    and isnull(publishedrate,0) = 0

        ) tracknumbers
    pivot (max(trackingnumber) for rownum in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) as pvt



-- Attached tracking and return tracking numbers to orders  
select os.Internal_id,
        os.client_id,
        os.altonumber,
        os.shipping_method,
        os.ship_date,
        os.parent_item_code,
        os.item_status,
        os.sn,
        os.order_status,
        isnull(t.tracknum1,'') + 
            case when isnull(t.tracknum2,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum2
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum3,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum3
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum4,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum4
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum5,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum5
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum6,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum6
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum7,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum7
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum8,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum8
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum9,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum9
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(t.tracknum10,'') <> ''
                then '|' + t.tracknum10
                else ''
            end as trackingnumbers,
        -- dl 6-12-2015 concatenating return_trackingnumber
        isnull(rt.tracknum1,'') + 
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum2,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum2
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum3,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum3
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum4,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum4
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum5,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum5
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum6,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum6
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum7,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum7
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum8,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum8
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum9,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum9
                else ''
            end +
            case when isnull(rt.tracknum10,'') <> ''
                then '|' + rt.tracknum10
                else ''
            end as return_trackingnumber
    from #Orders_Detail_Serials os
    left join #tracking t
        on os.internal_id = t.ordernumber
    left join #return_tracking rt
        on os.internal_id = rt.ordernumber
    order by os.ship_date, os.internal_id, os.client_id, os.altonumber, os.parent_item_code, os.sn



-- Clean up
drop table #Orders_Header_Info
drop table #Orders_Detail_Serials
drop table #tracking
drop table #return_tracking


END
```

Comment: You can use derived tables or CTE-s instead of temporary tables. However, there are advantages of using temporary tables, so I would leave it this way. Why do you want it changed?

Comment: So you inherited this Stored Procedure from someone else, you don't understand anything about SQL and thought: I'll post it to StackOverflow, they'll do the job for me?

Comment: @RazvanSocol The flow of work that uses this sp has changed, and no longer uses the table for daily data capture. I'm ok with SQL in general, but was never all that good with sp's.

Comment: When I wrote my previous comment, I thought you just want to get rid of the `#Orders_Detail_Serials` temporary table, but now I see you also got a `order_detail_serials` table. The value of the `sn` column from the final results comes from the `order_detail_serials` table. If you don't want to look to this table anymore, where do you get the values for the `sn` column from?

Comment: The new sn values would come from the order_serial table only. We no longer will be saving data in the order_detail_serials table and as such, no longer need it in the sp to pull from.